# how to get array index in angular 5 html?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular5

i have one array and i want display array index and it's value also in angular 5 html, here is my array,

```
Anil K Chaudhary
0: {is_present: "1", name: "Anil K Chaudhary", date: "22"}
1: {is_present: "0", name: "Anil K Chaudhary", date: "20"}

Laxman J chavda
0: {is_present: "0", name: "Laxman J chavda", date: "22"}
1: {is_present: "1", name: "Laxman J chavda", date: "20"}
```

below is my html code,

```
<tr *ngFor = "let getAttendanceData_new of getAttendanceData[key]">
  <td>{{getAttendanceData_new}}</td>   // i want to display array Index here. (e.g "Anil K Chaudhary", "Laxman J Chavda")

  <!-- ======== AND ALSO WANT HERE THEIR VALUE ======== -->
  <td *ngFor="let getDays_new of getDays;let i = index">
    <b *ngIf="getAttendanceData.is_present == 1 && getDays_new == getAttendanceData.date" style="color:green">P</b>
    <b *ngIf="getAttendanceData.is_present == 0 && getDays_new == getAttendanceData.date" style="color:lightgrey">A</b>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more so that others can understand and provide the solution that you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Till now the best / shortesr answer I found is

> Component side :

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

> Template side :

```
<div *ngFor='let key of objectKeys(jsonObj)'>
   Key: {{key}}

    <div *ngFor='let obj of jsonObj[key]'>
        {{ obj.title }}
        {{ obj.desc }}
    </div>

</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-key-loop)**

Comment: @Chaudhary, Glad to know , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` of Angular

```
{{ getAttendanceData_new | filter : {'name':index} }}
```

Comment: but i did not get name bcoz my array Index is not an integer it's NAME, so how can i get Name?

Comment: it give Error "The pipe 'filter' could not be found"